# Fix an unhandled promise rejection in react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, promise, react-navigation

I am trying to go to a new screen using react navigation but am running into a warning `[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.navigation.navigate')]`. No error is thrown (it is only a warning) but the app does not move to the next screen.

I have tried unsuccessfully to call a separate function holding the navigation code, and used an arrow function, but neither options worked.

Here is my code...

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  TextInput,
  AlertIOS,
} from 'react-native';

import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

import database from '../Database.js';

const db = new database();


class LoginForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Access Code"
          returnKeyType="go"
          onSubmitEditing={text => {
            db.isValidCode(text.nativeEvent.text).then(isValid => {
              if (isValid) {
                this.navigation.navigate('Create')// this throws warning
              } else {
                AlertIOS.alert(
                  "We're Sorry...",
                  'The code you entered was not found in the database! Please contact support for further assistance.'
                );
              }
            }).catch(function(error) {
              console.log(error);
              throw error;
            }) // this "catch" statement didn't fix the warning
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default withNavigation(LoginForm);
```

And the database file...

```
var firebase = require('firebase');

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp({
        apiKey: "key",
        authDomain: "domain",
        databaseURL: "url",
        storageBucket: "bucket",
    });
}

class Database {
    constructor() {
      this.codesRef = firebase.database().ref('codes');
    }

    async isValidCode(text) {
      let codeIsFound = false;
      let identifier = "";
      let db_snapshot = await this.codesRef.once('value');
       db_snapshot.forEach(code_snapshot => {
           if (text == code_snapshot.val().value) {
              codeIsFound = true;
              identifier = code_snapshot.key;
            }
       });
       return codeIsFound; 
    };

}

module.exports = Database;
```

I am not sure why the navigation isn't working. Everything worked fine and was much simpler when the function was in the same file that it was being used in. Any help / pointers are appreciated!

Comment: problem here is you should not throw error back from catch() or if you are throwing error from inside of catch you need handle that thrown error again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use:

`this.props.navigation.navigate('Create')`

instead of:

`this.navigation.navigate('Create')`

because `withNavigation` adds `navigation` to your component's properties not to the component itself.